# How can I perform a full-text search in GridDB using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, full-text-search, griddb

I am currently using a GridDB database and need to search for specific records in a column through a full-text search. However, I am having trouble with the SQL syntax for GridDB. Can you help me with this?

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT * FROM my_container WHERE CONTAINS(description, 'keyword')
```